# Classic ASP - Can't get expected response from SQL Server INSERT INTO work with OUTPUT INTO

Tags: asp-classic, sql-server-express

I'm trying to register a new user in an SQL Server DB, from Classic ASP

I appreciate the Classic ASP is antiquated, but I familiar with it and it does the job I need to to (generally).

Here's the code...

```
<%
Set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
Set con = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
con.ConnectionString="Provider=SQLOLEDB;" & _
    "Server=Server\SQLEXPRESS;" & _
    "Uid=IUSR;" & _
    "Pwd=Pwd;" & _
    "Database=DB"
con.Open

username="username"
password="password"


tsql="CREATE TABLE #newUserTable(UserID int); " & vbCrLf & _    
    "DECLARE @responseMessage NVARCHAR(50); " & vbCrLf & _
    "DECLARE @userID INT; " & vbCrLf & _
    "IF EXISTS (SELECT TOP 1 UserID FROM [dbo].[UserLogins] WHERE LoginName='" & username & "') " & vbCrLf & _
    "BEGIN " & vbCrLf & _
        "SET @responseMessage='User already exists' " & vbCrLf & _
    "END " & vbCrLf & _
    "ELSE " & vbCrLf &  _
    "BEGIN " & vbCrLf & _
        "DECLARE @salt UNIQUEIDENTIFIER=NEWID(); " & vbCrLf & _
        "BEGIN TRY " & vbCrLf & _
            "INSERT INTO dbo.UserLogins (LoginName,PasswordHash,Salt) " & vbCrLf & _
            "OUTPUT INSERTED.UserID INTO #newUserTable " & vbCrLf & _ 
            "VALUES ('" & username & "',HASHBYTES('SHA2_512', '" & password & "'+CAST(@salt AS NVARCHAR(36))),@salt); " & vbCrLf & _
            "SET @responseMessage=" & vbCrLf & _ 
            "CAST((SELECT userID FROM #newUserTable) AS NVARCHAR(50)); " & vbCrLf & _
        "END TRY " & vbCrLf & _
        "BEGIN CATCH " & vbCrLf & _
            "SET @responseMessage=ERROR_MESSAGE() " & vbCrLf & _ 
        "END CATCH " & vbCrLf & _
       "END " & vbCrLf & _
    "SELECT @responseMessage AS N'responseMessage'; " & vbCrLf & _
    "DROP TABLE #newUserTable"
'response.write tsql & "<hr />"
rs.open tsql, con
response.write rs("responseMessage")
rs.close
%>
```

When I attempt to add an existing user, I get the expected `User already exists` response, but when I attempt to add a new user, I get `Item cannot be found in the collection corresponding to the requested name or ordinal` which suggests that r`responseMessage` doesn't exist. If I output the tsql to the browser (replacing vbCrLf with "
") and run it in SQL Server, I get the `userID` returned as `responseMessage` as I would expect.

Can anyone suggest why this might be, and how I can correct it?

Comment: You say you're familiar with Classic ASP, but your code suggests otherwise. Is this just meant as a one off, or is it intended to be reused?

Comment: Yes, although not in the exact form it's presented in here. The ADODB stuff is in a separate file I call using the HTML '<!-- #include virtual="some folder/some file.asp" -->` and the variables are sent via a POST request, which I collect using `request.form("username")` and `request.form("password"). This is a single function page I call via jQuery AJAX. Am I missing something? Is there a big performance drain? Speed? Readability? Am I breaking conventions? Or is it that I am not declaring my variables?

Comment: The fact that if you do intend to use this code, be prepared for every sniffer on the web to hammer it with script kiddie SQL Injection attacks. *"Not declaring your variables"* is the least of your worries.

Comment: On the one hand, this is proof of concept stuff, and on the other hand, are you able to help improve this, then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your last command to `SELECT @responseMessage AS N'responseMessage'` (instead of the Drop).

You can also try using "`SET NOCOUNT ON`" to avoid count messages messing your results.

Also, you don't need to add `vbCrLf` to TSQL

Your code should look like this:

```
tsql="SET NOCOUNT ON; " &  _    
    "CREATE TABLE #newUserTable(UserID int); " &  _    
    "DECLARE @responseMessage NVARCHAR(50); " &  _
    "DECLARE @userID INT; " &  _
    "IF EXISTS (SELECT TOP 1 UserID FROM [dbo].[UserLogins] WHERE LoginName='" & username & "') " &  _
    "BEGIN " &  _
        "SET @responseMessage='User already exists' " &  _
    "END " &  _
    "ELSE " &   _
    "BEGIN " &  _
        "DECLARE @salt UNIQUEIDENTIFIER=NEWID(); " &  _
        "BEGIN TRY " &  _
            "INSERT INTO dbo.UserLogins (LoginName,PasswordHash,Salt) " &  _
            "OUTPUT INSERTED.UserID INTO #newUserTable " &  _ 
            "VALUES ('" & username & "',HASHBYTES('SHA2_512', '" & password & "'+CAST(@salt AS NVARCHAR(36))),@salt); " &  _
            "SET @responseMessage=" &  _ 
            "CAST((SELECT userID FROM #newUserTable) AS NVARCHAR(50)); " &  _
        "END TRY " &  _
        "BEGIN CATCH " &  _
            "SET @responseMessage=ERROR_MESSAGE() " &  _ 
        "END CATCH " &  _
       "END " &  _
    "DROP TABLE #newUserTable" &  _
    "SELECT @responseMessage AS N'responseMessage'; "
```

Comment: That has solved my issue, I cannot thank you enough for your quick and accurate response!

Comment: To add understanding to this answer, the last statement in your query must be the "select" in order to retrieve the value in your recordset.  By the way, You'd be MUCH better off creating a stored procedure with this code and passing in your parameters and retrieving the result.  So much easier to manage than concatenating these strings together, plus you're subject to SQL Injection.

Comment: @LarryBud I can only assume that's what was referring to above. I am new to SQL Server, and was concerned about giving my remote user EXEC permissions, but I take it that would be safer than what I'm currently doing.

Comment: It's not your user who would have the EXEC permission, it's the user that you set up and put in your connection string who would have the EXEC permission.